# Exponential function finding upper bound

Tags: exponential-function

$g(t) = \sqrt{1 − 8^t}$

The domain of $g(t)$ is all the values of t for which $8^t ≤ 1$.  To find the upper bound of this domain, I solve $8^t = 1$ and obtain that $t ≤ 0$? Is that correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely correct.